# Is there a way to access C's built in keywords like 'int' or 'char' or 'return'?

Tags: c, programming-languages

Is there a function or method to access C's keywords as mentioned in the question? The only way I can think of it is creating constants that will just be checked to see if any match, but that could be a lot to type, since there are a lot of keywords. I was hoping there was something. (New to C)

It is for a homework, so I cannot use regular expressions or parsing libraries. The purpose of the HW is to give my program a function and just return the identifiers, hence, why I was hoping there was a way to access the keywords easier than typing them all.

Example:

```
int foo (int args) 
{ 
    int x = 7; 
    char c = 'a'; 
    args = x + c; 
    return args; 
}
```

And it should return foo, args, x, c.

I am not looking for an answer, so a good hint if there is one would be great! If not, then just let me know that the tedious way is the only option.

Comment: What do you mean by "access C's built-in keywords?"  Do you just want a list of all the C reserved words?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a function?

Comment: This question is just bizarre.

Comment: @Rob the question is a basic teach-the-kids-to-tokenize-and-classify-input assignment; what's bizarre about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way of accessing the language from inside itself. Welcome to C, the land of do-it-yourself. Yes, you're going to have to tokenize the input stream and test each word. For tokenizing, check out the strcspn() function (a compliment string of " \t\n" (space, tab, newline) is probably good enough to get you going there.

Then build a NULL-terminated array of strings, e.g.

```
const char *identifiers [] = {
    "int",
    "continue",
     NULL
};
```

and iterate over that, doing strcmp() on the input vs the members of the array. If you hit the terminating NULL, you know it's not in the array (bonus points for using a sorted array and libc's bsearch(3) utilities!).

Comment: Haha, yes, a very warm welcome indeed. Typing out all the identifiers was what I was trying to avoid, but it seems like your tip makes the most sense. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Andy A smart man would use some command-line utilities to munge the C standard into the list you need, sorted or not. Just sayin.

Answer (score 2):

To identify the *identifiers* (as distinct from other token kinds) in the source, you need to lex the source.

One of the easiest ways to do this is to implement [Thompson's Algorithm](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) and use the preprocessing grammar from [the C99 language specification.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)  Once the source is lexed (or during lexing), you just need to create the list of preprocessing identifiers that are not C99 keywords.  It's quite straightforward to implement this in a couple hundred lines of code.

Comment: Man, that is insane overkill for an obviously CS 101 question. The OP should go for it if he's feeling gutsy and in need of some cool points, but shouldn't this level of instruction be focused on mastering basic, and fundamental, techniques?

Comment: @tbert:  Implementation of Thompson's Algorithm is an excellent CS 101 assignment.  It is a very basic and easily-implementable algorithm that demonstrates many important concepts of computer science.

Comment: Can I #include the grammar from the C99 spec? Or do I have to import it some other way?

Comment: @Andy:  Clause 6.4 of the linked specification describes the lexical elements of the C preprocessing grammar.

Comment: As a larger project, sure, but this reads as more a "write this by next class period" assignment. And if the basic building blocks aren't taught first, how then can we build towering cathedrals?

Comment: Thanks, I will read through it and see if I might go that route, though @tbert is right, it isn't a huge project, due in like a week and a half. The purpose is to kind of understand what a compiler does, but this resource is great because it is exactly what we are doing. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a program to read the file, building 'words' from sequences of alphanumeric characters.  You'll need a list of the keywords in C - which is quite short.  Then you'll compare the words you read against the list of keywords and print out the first occurrence of each (so you'll also need to store the words you've seen).

You'll need to know what you're expected to do with preprocessor directives; you may be able to ignore them.  You'll need to know how to recognize numbers, character strings and character constants.  You'll need to know how to recognize both `/* ... */` and `// ... to EOL` comments (or maybe not in the first version).

Eventually, you might get sucked into nastinesses such as strings that extend over line breaks and comments such as:

```
/\
\
* This is a C comment
*\
\
/
```

However, you can almost certainly omit those subtleties in a first pass.